# Sorting Problems with YYYY-M-DTHH:MM:SS column

Tags: python, sorting, escaping

I'm trying to run the following command in Python (v2.7) but I doesn't seem to work well. The command runs with no errors & the output file is created, but the data is not sorted as it should. However, if I run the command from the command line itself, it works perfectly.

Command:

```
os.system('paste ../temp_files/dp0* | sort -t T -k 2 >> ../temp_files/dp_test01_data.txt')
#this creates the output file, but the data inside is not sorted
```

When I run this in command line outside of python (after running above line):

```
cat ../temp_files/dp_test01_data.txt |sort -t T -k 2
#The data gets sorted with no problem
```

All I am trying to do is sort a file ("dp_test01_data.txt") based on column 8 (YYYY-M-DTHH:MM:SS) that has multiple lines. Eg.:
A B C E F 2018-9-17T14:27:01 G H

Any thoughts/suggestions on how I could tackle this would be amazing... Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your `os.system` command uses `>>`, meaning the output of `paste` is _appended_ to the output file, so any existing lines in the file may not not be sorted relative to the newly added lines.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the note! Do you happen to have any suggestions/example on how I could get around this?

Comment: John Gordon - thanks! I actually figured out how to do this. All I did was to break up the commands in order to allow for the sorting to be implemented. Worked perfectly!   Thank you very much again... I would have never thought that was the issue =)